# Determine if any rows returned by Laravel DB query before calling chunk?

Tags: mysql, laravel, database

I have a query prepared using the database query builder (NOT eloquent).

It returns, by design, several million rows, therefore I'm using `chunk()` to keep memory use under control:

```
$query->orderBy('id')->chunk(25000, function (\Illuminate\Support\Collection $batch) use ($csv) {

    $batch->map(function ($record) {
        return $this->parseForTextOutput($record);
    })->pipe(function ($parsed) use ($csv) {
        $csv->insertAll($parsed);
    });
});
```

(where $query is a prepared query, `DB::table('data')->leftJoin('…` etc.)

It would be convenient **to know if there are ANY rows at all (yes/no), either *before* calling the class method which contains chunk(), or if there's a method I can chain in *before* chunk()**, so I can divert people back to the form with an error message.

Is that even possible?

To reiterate, I don't need an exact row count,, just if there are any. There are various WHERE clauses so I can't just count the rows in the table.

Here's a standalone conditional I've used, but the `->get()` quickly eats all the RAM as the rows increase.

```
if ($query->get()->count() == 0) {
    return back()->withInput()->withErrors('No results found.');
}
```

(thanks)

Comment: You could just do `$query->count()` instead of getting all of the results. That should speed things up considerably.

Answer (score 0):

As @JoelHinz said you shouldn't use `->get()` as it will fetch all the records making `->chunk()` useless.

You don't even need `($query->count() == 0)` you can do `if ($query->exists()) {...}` and it will return `true` / `false`